# logical to physical addressing

Tags: operating-systems, virtual-memory

Consider the page table below (all numbers are in hex) and assume 1 KB page size. Assume 16-bit logical address and 20-bit physical address.

a.What are the page numbers and offsets for the following logical addresses: 1.1CC4  2.3A98 3.43FC 4.600C 5.2BD0 6.0

b.provide the physical address for each part a:

I figured out part a. I'm stuck on part b. Reason being, we're given a table with valid / invalid bit and a frame number. I know normally you would convert the hex value to binary and use the first set of bits to determine the page number which is used as a index to get the frame number. The issue is that information doesn't exist. This is the only info given...

[image: table]

I'm not sure what im doing wrong here. For example, I calculated 1CC4 being 1 using the first 4 bits. Since there's no index and no 1 in the frame number I guessed a page fault. Sadly, that can't be true because the page fault should only occur if the valid bit is set to 0. Any ideas on what i'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Complete page tables for the whole logical address space are a waste of space. Most logical pages have no physical memory counterpart - they have only a file storage existence. For physical memory, you want a look-aside (associative) buffer. All else is effluvia of the male ox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this kind of question, you always need to make sure first that you know how the logical address will be broken down.

In this case, you have a 16-bit logical address, with pages that are 1KB. 1024 == 2^10. So, you need 10 bits for offset, leaving 6 bits for the page number.

So, 0x1CC4 => 0001110011000100 => 000111 (page# 7) --- 0011000100 (offset=0xC4)

Entry 7 in your page table is valid and maps to frame 0x22.

Concatenate the frame number and the offset to get the physical address.

00001000100011000100 = 0x88C4